# Adobe Flex control missing vertical scroll bar

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, scrollbar

I have a canvas containing a datagrid.  I set horizontal and vertical scroll to 'off' for the canvas, and set both to 'auto' for the DG.  This works until I have a larger number of columns in the DG (>=16), then the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear.  Anyone seen this and, better yet, have an answer?

Comment: Do you mean the horizontal scroller appears and the vertical scroller disappears at the same time?  Do the two scrollers' behaviors seem related at all?

Comment: No, the horiz scroller is always there but the vert scroller disappears when more than 15 columns are created in the DG.  See my "solution" below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution, if not an answer.  The outer container was specified with fixed height and width, and the inner DG was set to 100% height and width.  Setting the DG height and width to fixed values a bit smaller than the outer container did the trick.  Still, it seems "100%" should work.